# Why don't replace HTML with JSON as base web design technology?

Tags: html, json

Since JSON shows a lot of benefits over HTML, why don't just abandon HTML?
Qt frameworks with QML shows it is perfectly possible to use JSON to design rich content

**EDIT:**

Many of you think about this question in terms of performance vs html but i'm not about that.

HTML is just less readable and it's not enough per-se to describe UI behavior, look and feel. Maybe a technology shift is needed. I think from the developer point of view.

What about a browser capable of rendering a QML like web-page for example? QT with QML uses google V8 engine to do its work.

If you can write a web page in a technology that is not HTML, people will start using it.
Browser could support HTML for a long time and allow developers to code with less stress

Comment: I have a better question. Why?

Comment: What benefits did you have in mind? Expand on them please.

Comment: legacy and inertia, 2 of the most powerful forces in computer development

Comment: You can save traffic and storage for example

Comment: I suppose you could write a browser that renders pure JSON "pages" instead of HTML pages. Do that as a proof of concept, maybe it will catch on... ?

Comment: Btw, "perfectly possible" is never a good enough reason to do something in itself.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491

Comment: Another justification would be the horror that HTML represents as a terrible, cancerous spec that has not so much evolved over time as consumed the internet with the same relationship that Godzilla enjoys with Tokyo.

Comment: Why don't you create a javascript library that translates JSON into HTML to test it out?  All you'd need is a single <script> tag.

Comment: JSON is a data interchange format. It is a category error to compare it with HTML. If you intend to use HTML DOM concepts and identifiers, implying HTML definitions for them, you are just referring to the *serialization* of HTML (the syntax used to linearize elements to a string of text).

Comment: You might want to sit down and try writing what would be a simple web page as pure json.  You know, with `<a href="foo.html">foo <b>bar</b></a>` links and the like.  Just straight up old school html... and then have the equivalent json style page and see if you can read it, or if you would even be able to write it out by hand in a text editor (or part of a jsp or php page) and consider the savings you would be gaining with this format.

Comment: This question is based on the premise that you find HTML hard to read. That is an opinion that others may or may not agree with. That also makes the answers primarily based on opinion, rather than expertise. Those questions/answers aren't a good fit for the StackExchange Q&A format.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Toilet paper was invented on the premise that someone found leaves and wood hard to use. That is an opinion that other may or may not agree with. But today we use toilet paper because a change had to be made.

Comment: @sam That doesn't mean that asking about why toilet paper hasn't replaced leaves yet is a good Q&A question in an era that there is no consensus on which is really better. It might create a nice discussion, but that is not what this place is for.

Comment: why? here's why: `html.body.a('my-id').link('http://www.google.com')` natively and purely JS instead of parsing html with jquery or using javascript `getElementById()` things...

Answer (score 5):

You are assuming JSON is always better than HTML, which is controversial at best (see MainMa's answer). But let's assume you're right. Why don't we get rid of HTML?

The surface answer is compatibility, but why is compatibility even an issue? The fundamental reason you can't make these kinds of changes on the web is because the web is a decentralized system built on [communication protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_protocol). So even if a majority of the web switched to JSON tomorrow, any cohort of the web still using HTML could function. There is no central switch.

Answer (score 3):

While JSON has a benefit in terms of **size** (and so bandwidth) and **simplicity** (slightly easier to parse for smartphones), such major change of replacing one language by another would be too disruptive to justify the minor gains in bandwidth and performance. Such gains were maybe relevant ten years ago where mobile devices were very limited in terms of CPU and when many people had only access to low-speed internet, but today, it's much less relevant.

If you're not convinced, take an ordinary e-commerce website, measure the time spent:

1. Downloading and parsing (sometimes minified and usually gzipped and cached on client side) HTML.

and compare it to the time it takes to:

1. Download minified JavaScript source,
2. Download images,
3. Download CSS,
4. Parse CSS,
5. Render the page,
6. Execute JavaScript.

Now, if you identified that after minifying HTML, gziping it and adding client-side caching, the loading and the parsing of HTML is still *the bottleneck* on your website, nothing forbids you, using current standards, to make a fully AJAX website, sending practically only JSON to your users.

Comment: "nothing forbids you, using current standards, to make a fully AJAX website, sending practically only JSON to your users" And then you have customers who don't want any javascript, just sayin ;)

Comment: I don't care about performance, i look at this from the developer point of view. Today web programming is very messy

Comment: The question is not about HTML vs dynamically constructing a webpage using JS + JSON, it's about moving from HTML to JSON as the language parsed by browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Because the change would bring more pain than benefit.

Let's assume that you are right and that JSON is better than HTML for the job of defining web pages. Well, okay, but that's not enough to justify the change. There would have to be tangible benefit.  Maybe raw web pages would be easier to maintain and quicker to download -- but we mostly don't edit raw HTML anymore, and download time is mostly about server load and media size.

On the other hand, the cost of change would be *horrific*.

Sorry to be cynical, but there (IMO) you go.

Comment: I would disagree here. You make it sound like it is either HTML or JSON. Which it isn't. There is a reason for doctype. We could easily declare json as a doctype and use both.
We just need a way for the browser to parse it and apply css to it. 

This of course may require some changes, but the change would be far from horrific. Arguably many websites already do this, but with a round about way from using html templates rendered from json. We would simply be saving a step. 

While the bandwidth from the initial load, but the reduced file size for rendering templates.

Comment: @DillonBurnett -- OPs question said "replace".  Not use alongside.

Comment: I know. I'm not saying that 1 webpage can use both. What I'm was trying to explain is that you could have 2 different standards. Older websites can still use traditional HTML and new ones could use JSON. The browser should be able to tell them apart from the doctype. Just like it does with HTML and XML.